# Where is an argsort implementation in well-known C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, sorting

I need an argsort in my c++ code.  I see some people write their own argsort in C++ like this one https://medium.com/@sddkal/my-take-on-c-argsort-function-bfb59845d30c.  But what would be a built-in one or one from a well-known library? Implementations from such libraries should have better performance presumably (like std::vector should have better performance than a hand-crafted one.)

Argsort is to returns a list of index positions as if our target list is sorted.  See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html for a description in python's implementation in Numpy for example.

Comment: Well I was going to suggest using the standard sort with a comparator that looks up the values to compare from another vector - but that's exactly what your article does. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Rup Implementations from well-known should have better performance presumably.

Comment: Better performance than what? According to what metrics? Did you measure it? Did you find a bottleneck? Did you analyse the algorithmic complexity of the approach and find it lacking? What?

Comment: It is like std::vector should have better performance than a hand-crafted one.   @AsteroidsWithWings?

Comment: The top-scoring answer in the duplicate post should be perfectly adequate.  This is (almost) as performant as you'll get in C++, or anything for that matter.  The only tiny inefficiency is that the vector resize will unnecessarily initialize all that memory before then writing it again with `std::iota`.  But you're unlikely to notice any appreciable difference.  This is a good demonstration of having a flexible set of tools and algorithms to perform specific tasks such as yours, without requiring such specific implementations cluttering the standard library.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e09ec88779a85170 ?

Comment: That makes sense, @paddy

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings That is what Strousttrup said in his book. But of course he may be wrong.

Comment: questions must be self-contained. Besides medium.com is notorious for limiting the number of views each month so lots of people won't be able to read the article to understand what argsort is

Comment: @zell I doubt he said that. If he did, yes, he was wrong.